# Why does adding a handler to Activated stop the window from appearing?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

When my application's main window opens, I want another window to open alongside it as a companion. So I added a handler for the Activated event:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // ...

    Activated += OnFirstActivation;

    // ...
}

private void OnFirstActivation(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    _otherWindow.Owner = this;
    _otherWindow.Show();
    Activated -= OnFirstActivation;
}
```

Before making this change, the main window would pop up and take focus upon being activated. With this change in place, neither window does this when the main window is activated. Why not?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but is there some particular reason why you're going through the trouble to subscribe and unsubscribe the `Activated` event, instead of just handling the `Loaded` event?

Comment: Do you want to know why, or do you want to know how to show two forms and activating either?

Comment: Cody Gray, no there isn't; I lack the familiarity with WPF to know which of those two I ought to use. CodeCaster, the second one I suppose. But understanding the answer to the question would also be useful.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about WPF either, but it seems pretty obvious you are doing it the wrong way when you have to subscribe to the event and then immediately unsubscribe. Activated gets raised every time the window is activated. You only want to be notified the first time it gets Loaded. Aside from that, just to be clear, are you saying that neither window shows up? Or that neither window gets activated? Or that only one window shows up?

Comment: Regardless of whether I add the handler to Loaded or to Activated (NB. in every case I am unsubscribing from the same one I subscribe to), the same behaviour is observed: the windows are created silently and do not pop up or take focus. If I subscribe to neither, then the main window pops up and takes focus, but obviously the other window is not created. If I subscribe to Loaded and add a call to Activate() at the end of OnFirstLoad() (as the method is appropriately named in that scenario), then I see the expected behaviour.

Comment: Okay, that's what I wanted to know. It sounded in your question like neither window was appearing, but really they are both just appearing without focus. That's because you are manipulating the focus. That's monkeying with Windows' default focus assignment algorithm. Whenever an application launches a window, that window is given the focus by default. But if that window gives up the focus, focus will go to something else. Hard to explain in a comment. Anyway, the solution is to display the second window *without the focus*. That will ensure the first window is activated and focused as normal.